# How do you configure Grails Datasources Plugin to have a schema search path on a datasource?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres and also the Datasources plugin.

Rails has a property called schema_search_path.  Is there an equivalent in Grails?

I have two schemas, hk and public in the database.

Where can I specify a search path for the schema or a specific schema name?

I was able to make this work using the syntax like the following on the individual class.

static mapping = {
    table name:'he_stats_item_summary_keywords', schema:'he'
}

However, it would still be nice to know if there was an equivalent to the schema_search_path on the datasource.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution found at:

[PostgreSQL Default Schema in DataSource](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/PostgreSQL-Default-Schema-in-DataSource-td2243486.html)
[Add support the hibernate.default_schema property to the _DataSource.groovy file](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1132)

development {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/deploy"
      hibernate.default_schema = "turnkey_dev"
      dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    }
  }